# Add test jars in maven-jetty-plugin or create test-war with maven-war-plugin

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using maven to build a multi-module webapp. I would like to run my integration tests in their own module and use the jetty plugin. In order to get everything to work I will need to add a couple of jars to the classpath for the war but I see no option for such a thing in the documentation http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#deploy-war-running-pre-assembled-war

I am able to deploy the war but it fails because it's missing the two jars I need to add.

Is there a way for me to add a couple extra jars to the plugin configuration?

If not, is there a way for me to package a "test-war" like you can do with test-jar in maven?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to extend the web application classpath with the jetty-maven-plugin. The most appropriated for you would be to set the `extraClasspath` field in the `webAppConfig` block of your plugin configuration:

```
<configuration>
 ...
 <webAppConfig>
  ...
  <extraClasspath>path/to/your/custom-dependency.jar</extraClasspath>
 </webAppConfig>
</configuration>
```

The documentation is not very consistent about that. But the [javadoc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setExtraClasspath%28java.lang.String%29) is quite clear.

You can find relevant configuration examples on my [jetty plugin wiki page](http://www.benoitschweblin.com/2013/03/run-jetty-in-maven-life-cycle.html).

Comment: nice page, but can you give the webAppConfig to a war using the deploy-war in a module that is not of war packaging type?  It seems like I tried that and it didn't work. I finally gave up and moved the integration tests back into my war project.

Comment: I would say yes, but I haven't tested it. I think the best thing to do is to package a custom war for your integration tests. You can do that by using the war overlay functionality to include your production war into your test war, or, even better, you can package both of them in the same project using maven classifiers. See [this link](http://www.jayway.com/2010/01/21/one-artifact-with-multiple-configurations-in-maven/).

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependencies directly to the plugin's `<dependencies/>`. No need for scopes or anything -- they'll not enter your final artifact, but rather -- only be used by the Jetty plugin during execution.

Comment: I won't be able to test it until tonight. Are they added to the container classpath or the webapp classpath in this case?

Comment: Well, this way it's to the container, but I believe there was a way to define the extra classpath as well.

Comment: heh, and that's my question. I would like to believe there is a way, but what is the way? The documentation on the "deploy-war" goal for the jetty plugin is very sparse.